# spark streamingcontext loaded from checkpoint has no hadoopConf settings

Tags: azure, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Can't recover from checkpointing to Azure blob storage with a `wasbs://...` url

Using Standalone Spark 2.0.2 in cluster mode.

```
val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointPath, () => createSSC(), hadoopConf)
```

I set `fs.azure` and `fs.azure.account.key.$account.blob.core.windows.net` via the `hadoopConf` in `hadoopConf.set` and redundantly in the createSSC function via `sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set`

The job successfully writes checkpointing files while running and runs until I stop it.

When I restart it, the context created from checkpointing data doesn't have the hadoopConf info to re-access `wasbs://` storage and throws an error saying it can't create container with anonymous access.

What am I missing?  I've found a couple similar posts about S3 but no clear solution.

The error:

[image]

*More details: this happens after restarting from checkpointing inside the kafka 0.10.1.1 connector and I've confirmed that the sparkContext.hadoopConf attached to that RDD does have the correct key.*

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem programmatically other that core-site.xml one?

Comment: not yet - I've been running a sed script before the submit script updating the core-site.xml from an env var.  not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

Put the key in the spark `core-site.xml`.  I was trying to avoid this because the credentials are a deploy-time setting - I won't set these at compile time or docker image build time.

Before my container calls `spark-submit`, it now creates the `/opt/spark/conf/core-site.xml` file from the template below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>fs.azure</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.azure.account.key.[CHECKPOINT_BLOB_ACCOUNT].blob.core.windows.net</name>
    <value>[CHECKPOINT_BLOB_KEY]</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```