# How to store checkpoints of a spark job (Structured Streaming) directly on Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Use case: We want to persist the checkpoint data on Azure Blob instead of local file system to analyse few metrics.

While the workaround given in the below post works well for checkpointing on local filesystem. Extending the below approach to connect to Azure Blob didn't work.
([spark streamingcontext loaded from checkpoint has no hadoopConf settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096006/spark-streamingcontext-loaded-from-checkpoint-has-no-hadoopconf-settings))

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Azure FS details on the SQLContext of the SparkSession.

```
val azureUrl = "abfs://XXXX.dfs.core.windows.net"
sqlContext.setConf("fs.defaultFS", azureUrl)
```

And of course, use `sqlContext.setConf`to set other configurations if needed, to support the way you use Azure Blob (e.g. the authentication methods) - see various keys [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/azurebfs/constants/ConfigurationKeys.html).
You need the `hadoop-azure` library for that.

Spark Structured Streaming will use this in order to write and read the checkpoints.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/production

They have an option to checkpoint to DBFS if you use Azure Databricks job

```
streamingDataFrame.writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", "dbfs://outputPath/")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs://checkpointPath")
  .start()
```